# Uniform/normal convergences of $\sum_{n\geq 0} f_n(x)$ and $\sum_{n\geq 0} g_n(x)$ imply the uniform/normal conv. of $\sum_{n\geq 0} f_n(x)+g(x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, uniform-convergence

Consider two function series $\sum_{n\geq 0} f_n(x)$ and $\sum_{n\geq 0} g_n(x)$. I know that
$$\sum_{n\geq 0} f_n(x) \mathrm{\,\, converges \,\,\, conditionally \,\,\, and } \sum_{n\geq 0} g_n(x) \mathrm{\,\, converges \,\,\, conditionally} \implies \sum_{n\geq 0} (f_n(x)+g_n(x)) \mathrm{\,\, converges \,\,\, conditionally}$$
And that
$$\sum_{n\geq 0} f_n(x) \mathrm{\,\, converges \,\,\, absolutely \,\,\, and } \sum_{n\geq 0} g_n(x) \mathrm{\,\, converges \,\,\, absolutely} \implies \sum_{n\geq 0} (f_n(x)+g_n(x)) \mathrm{\,\, converges \,\,\, absolutely}$$

---

Are these implications extended to the cases of uniform and normal convergence.

That is, do the following implications hold?

$$\sum_{n\geq 0} f_n(x) \mathrm{\,\, converges \,\,\, uniformly \,\,\, and } \sum_{n\geq 0} g_n(x) \mathrm{\,\, converges \,\,\, uniformly} \implies \sum_{n\geq 0} (f_n(x)+g_n(x)) \mathrm{\,\, converges \,\,\, uniformly}$$

$$\sum_{n\geq 0} f_n(x) \mathrm{\,\, converges \,\,\, normally \,\,\, and } \sum_{n\geq 0} g_n(x) \mathrm{\,\, converges \,\,\, normally} \implies \sum_{n\geq 0} (f_n(x)+g_n(x)) \mathrm{\,\, converges \,\,\, normally}$$

If it is not true in general, does it hold at least for power series?

I did not find any theorem or proof on this, so it would be great to have some reference where to learn more about this.

Comment: What's "total" convergence? Did you mean normal convengence?

Comment: @Luca Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are saying that $\sum f_n$ and $\sum g_n$, defined in a set $A$ converge uniformly.

This means that $\forall \epsilon' > 0 \ \exists N'_{\epsilon'} \ / \forall n > N', \forall x \in A \ $ we have

$$
|\sum_{k=0}^n f_k - f | < \epsilon'
$$

and $\forall \epsilon'' > 0 \ \exists N''_{\epsilon''} \ / \forall n > N'', \forall x \in A \ $ we have
$$
|\sum_{k=0}^n g_k - g | < \epsilon''.
$$

Well, suppose we are given an $ \epsilon > 0$: we apply the hypothesis to our two series taking $ \epsilon' = \epsilon'' = \frac 12 \epsilon $:

By uniform convergence we find $N', N''$ such that
$$
|\sum_{k=0}^n f_k - f | < \frac 12 \epsilon \qquad
|\sum_{k=0}^n g_k - g | < \frac 12 \epsilon.
$$

Take $N = \max \{ N', N''\} $.  Now, $\quad \forall n > N, \ \forall x \in A \ $ we have

$$
|\sum_{k=0}^n (f_k + g_k) - (f + g) | =  |\sum_{k=0}^n f_k - f + \sum_{k=0}^n g_k -  g | \leq |\sum_{k=0}^n f_k - f | + |\sum_{k=0}^n g_k -  g | < \frac 12 \epsilon + \frac 12 \epsilon = \epsilon.
$$

Now, if $\sum f_n$ and $\sum g_n$, always defined in a $A$, converge normally, 
we have that $ \ \exists m_n, \ \exists m'_n \ /  \forall x \in A \ \forall n $ we have

$$
| f_n | \leq m_n \qquad  | g_n | \leq m'_n
$$

and $\exists m, m' \in \mathbb R $

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} m_k  = m  \qquad  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} m'_k  = m'. 
$$

But obviously

$$
|f_n + g_n| \leq |f_n| + |g_n| \leq m_n + m'_n
$$

Since $m_k, \ m'_k \ $ are positive and their sums converge, you can say that

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} ( m_k + m'_k )  =  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} m_k + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} m'_k   = m + m'. 
$$

You can always reorder positive convergent series.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! If I may ask, does something hold for the reverse? That is, from the uniform/normal convergence of $\sum g_n+f_n$ can I conclude something on $\sum f_n$ and $\sum g_n$? My guess would be that in general nothing can be said about it

Comment: Well, if $f_n $ and $g_n$ are not positive, you cannot say anything: just take $f_n = - g_n$ for any $f_n$. If they are positive (or both negative), however, you can.